# How cron job works

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

I am new to linux.
I have a cron job 'A' which should run every week
i used `crontab-e` to set it let say 3rd march 15:00 i did this.

Now today (6th march) i have to add another job 'B' which should run every 2 months so if i am doing today using `crontab -e` and appending it 
what will happen to my first job `A`? will it reset it to start from today?

Comment: If set to run on, say Saturday, then it will not run today even if you make changes to other entries. But for a proper answer please add the actual crontab entries you created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cron jobs are processed independently, and as long as there are no errors in the file (which could cause it to stop working altogether) it does not matter which order the entries are in, they will all be executed at the appropriate time.

The existing jobs will not be rescheduled because of changes to the file (but may he rescheduled if you change the date/time).